# Sending string from AndroidLauncher to MyGdxGame

Tags: java, android, libgdx, native

I am trying to create a chess app, I get move information from Bluetooth, then I need to send it to method located in the core class. Also, I need to start a function that is in `AndroidLauncher` when a button from core class has been clicked.

**AndroidLauncher:**

```
public  class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication  {
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    BluetoothDevice mmDevice = null;

    final byte delimiter = 33;
    int readBufferPosition = 0;
    public void sendBtMsg(String msg2send){
        //UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        try {

            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            if (!mmSocket.isConnected()){
                mmSocket.connect();
            }

            String msg = msg2send;
            //msg += "\n";
            OutputStream mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        MyGdxGame game = new MyGdxGame();
        View gameView = initializeForView(game, config);
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        final class workerThread implements Runnable {

          private String btMsg;

          public workerThread(String msg) {
            btMsg = msg;
          }

          public void run()
          {
            sendBtMsg(btMsg);
            while(1 == 1) {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    int bytesAvailable;
                    boolean workDone = false;

                    try {


                        final InputStream mmInputStream;
                        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                        bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {

                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    //The variable data now contains our full command
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            char first = data.charAt(0);
                                            if( first == 'm'){
                                                new AsyncLogin().execute(data.substring(1),"-", "0");
                                            } else {
                                                new AsyncLogin().execute("-",data, "0");
                                            }
                                            //myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });

                                    workDone = true;
                                    break;


                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }

                            if (workDone == true){
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
    // end light off button handler

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("raspberrypi")) //Note, you will need to change this to match the name of your device
            {
                Log.e("Aquarium",device.getName());
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyGdxGame**

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public static int V_WIDTH = 720;//720
    public static int V_HEIGHT = 1280;//1280
    private String slogin = "Prisijungimas",sreg= "Registracija",sai = 
    "Kompiuteris",shuman = "Ieškoti oponento",sboard;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture bdt,blt,kdt,klt,ndt,nlt,pdt,plt,qdt,qlt,rdt,rlt;
    OrthographicCamera camera; 

    public Viewport viewport;
    private ShowScreen screen = ShowScreen.login;
    BitmapFont font,font2; 
    float rh, rw;
    float startpos[][][] = new float[9][9][2];//cia grido pozicijos [eile]
    [stulpelis][x/y]
    float fig_pos[][]= new float[32][6];// [figuros id]
    [x/y/newx/newy/movingx/movingy]
    int fig_laukelis[][] = new int[32][2];//[figuros id][eile/stulpelis]
    //figuru movinimui
    int oldRow;
    int newRow;
    int oldCol;
    int newCol;


    ShapeRenderer shape;//renderina shapus as buttons
    GlyphLayout layout;
    //test string
    String test = "move example 1";


    @Override
    public void create() {
        //kai kuriuos var'us reikia initialaizint dar karta kad sukurti ale tuscia array
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        shape = new ShapeRenderer();
        font = new BitmapFont();//cia kad spausdinti texta
        font2 = new BitmapFont();//cia kad spausdinti texta lentoj
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(); //nustatom cameros dydi
        viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),camera);//fitinam i screena
        viewport.apply();//reikia apply kitaip viewporto dydis nebus issaugotas
        //gaunam ratio
        rw = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float) V_WIDTH;
        rh = (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float) V_HEIGHT;
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);//nustatom cameros pozicija per viduti cameros view
        //uzrkaunam img
        //prima uzkraunam i manageri
        bdt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_bdt60.png");
        blt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_blt60.png");
        kdt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_kdt60.png");
        klt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_klt60.png");
        ndt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_ndt60.png");
        nlt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_nlt60.png");
        pdt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_pdt60.png");
        plt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_plt60.png");
        qdt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_qdt60.png");
        qlt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_qlt60.png");
        rdt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_rdt60.png");
        rlt = new Texture("chess_fig/chess_rlt60.png");
        //font
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("comics_bold.ttf"));//gali pasikeisti i bet koki kita fonta jei nori
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = (int) (50*(rw/rh));//dydis
        font = generator.generateFont(parameter);///issaugom sugeneratinta fonta
        font.setColor(255 / 255f, 255 / 255f, 255 / 255f, 1);
        parameter.size = (int)(150*(rw/rh));
        font2 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        font2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //gaunam grida

        for(int stulpeis = 0;stulpeis<9;stulpeis++){
        for(int eile = 0;eile<9;eile++){
              startpos[eile][stulpeis][0]=0+(camera.viewportWidth/9*stulpeis);//x
              startpos[eile][stulpeis][1]=0+(camera.viewportWidth/9*eile);//y
          }

        }
    private void movefig(String coord) {

        //nuskaitom stringa ir priskiriam teisingas reiksmes
        for (int index = 0; index < 4;
             index++) {
            char aChar = coord.charAt(index);
            if(index==0){
                if(aChar=='A'){
                    oldCol=1;
                }else if(aChar=='B'){
                    oldCol=2;
                }else if(aChar=='C'){
                    oldCol=3;
                }else if(aChar=='D'){
                    oldCol=4;
                }else if(aChar=='E'){
                    oldCol=5;
                }else if(aChar=='F'){
                    oldCol=6;
                }else if(aChar== 'G'){
                    oldCol=7;
                }else if(aChar == 'H'){
                    oldCol=8;
                }
            }else if(index==1){
                if(aChar=='1'){
                    oldRow=1;
                }else if(aChar=='2'){
                    oldRow=2;
                }else if(aChar=='3'){
                    oldRow=3;
                }else if(aChar=='4'){
                    oldRow=4;
                }else if(aChar=='5'){
                    oldRow=5;
                }else if(aChar=='6'){
                    oldRow=6;
                }else if(aChar== '7'){
                    oldRow=7;
                }else if(aChar == '8'){
                    oldRow=8;
                }
            }else if(index==2){
                if(aChar=='A'){
                    newCol=1;
                }else if(aChar=='B'){
                    newCol=2;
                }else if(aChar=='C'){
                    newCol=3;
                }else if(aChar=='D'){
                    newCol=4;
                }else if(aChar=='E'){
                    newCol=5;
                }else if(aChar=='F'){
                    newCol=6;
                }else if(aChar== 'G'){
                    newCol=7;
                }else if(aChar == 'H'){
                    newCol=8;
                }
            }else if(index==3){
                if(aChar=='1'){
                    newRow=1;
                }else if(aChar=='2'){
                    newRow=2;
                }else if(aChar=='3'){
                    newRow=3;
                }else if(aChar=='4'){
                    newRow=4;
                }else if(aChar=='5'){
                    newRow=5;
                }else if(aChar=='6'){
                    newRow=6;
                }else if(aChar== '7'){
                    newRow=7;
                }else if(aChar == '8'){
                    newRow=8;
                }
            }
        }
        //ieskom figureles kuri butu senoj pozicioj
        for(int f = 0;f<32;f++){
            if(fig_laukelis[f][0]==oldRow && fig_laukelis[f][1]==oldCol){
                //nzn kas cia nutiko bet cia susimaiso row ir collumai ;/
                fig_pos[f][2]=(camera.viewportWidth/9)*(newCol);
                fig_pos[f][3]=(camera.viewportWidth/9)*(newRow);
                //atnaujinam figuros laukeli
                fig_laukelis[f][0]=newRow;
                fig_laukelis[f][1]=newCol;
                //radom tad baigiam cikla
                f=33;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I need to do is call movefig method when I get data from Bluetooth in AndroidLauncher `handler.post(new Runnable() {` part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `movefig()` of `MyGdxGame` public so that you can access from any package.

```
MyGdxGame gdxGame;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
     gdxGame = new MyGdxGame();
     View gameView = initializeForView(gdxGame, config);

     setContentView(gameView);
}
```

Now you've reference of `MyGdxGame`, You can call `movefig()` inside `AndroidLauncher` class.

---

You need [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) by which you make call `core module` to `android module`

Create an interface inside your `core` module

```
public interface Service {

    void doSomeThing();
}
```

Implement this interface in `AndroidLauncher` class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements Service {
    MyGdxGame gdxGame;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        gdxGame = new MyGdxGame(this);
        View gameView = initializeForView(gdxGame, config);

        setContentView(gameView);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //do what you want 
    } 

    ...
}
```

Keep reference of `Service` that comes from platform so create parameterised constructor of `MyGdxGame`

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

   Service service;          

   public MyGdxGame(Service service){
       this.service=service;
   }

   ...
}
```